# impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging.

Tags: symmetricds

I am srikanth,
In my project I want to replicate data between "sqlite" and "mysql"... sym tables are created in "mysql" database.. But data is not replication.. i got following exception in "symmetric log file", "org.jumpmind.db.sql.SqlException: Cannot execute statement: impossible to write to binary log since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT and at least one table uses a storage engine limited to row-based logging. InnoDB is limited to row-logging when transaction isolation level is READ COMMITTED or READ UNCOMMITTED"....May i know the reason..... thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

As recommended on [Atlassian's site](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/MySQL+Binary+Logging+Problem+with+InnoDB+When+Creating+a+Workflow):

> To change to row based binary logging, set the following in
>   /etc/my.cnf (or your my.cnf if it's elsewhere):

```
binlog_format=row
```

> Please see
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/binary-log-setting.html for
>   more information.